# Unable to access all the properties from properties file with java configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot

With Java configuration(@ConfigurationProperties) i can access only single word properties, if i want to access properties with suffix(Ex:server.port,server.address) i need to add **server** to the configuaration(**@ConfigurationProperties("server")**).

I need all the properties from properties file how can i access it?

```
//application.properties
spring.application.name=com-example
server.port=8080
minimum=200
maximum=20000
```

```
//Configuration.java

package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("server")
public class Configuration {
    private int minimum;
    private int maximum;
    private int port;

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    protected Configuration() {

    }

    public Configuration(int minimum, int maximum, int port) {
        super();
        this.minimum = minimum;
        this.maximum = maximum;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public int getMinimum() {
        return minimum;
    }

    public void setMinimum(int minimum) {
        this.minimum = minimum;
    }

    public int getMaximum() {
        return maximum;
    }

    public void setMaximum(int maximum) {
        this.maximum = maximum;
    }

}
```

```
//ExampleController.java

package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @Autowired
    private Configuration configuration;

    @GetMapping("/properties")
    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return new Configuration(configuration.getMinimum(), configuration.getMaximum(),
                configuration.getPort());
    }
}
```

Comment: In your properties, try renaming "minimum" and "maximum" to "server.minimum" and "server.maximum"

Comment: Dear @vc73 If i have 100 properties? if i have xyz.minimum, abc.maximum? and i want spring.application.name,how can access it?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) guide your class should be annotated with  `@Configuration` and your main application should have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` for your class.

Comment: This is a convention by design. You need to either avoid using "." or annotate the prefix(es) in order to get all properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class Configuration {
    @Value("${minimum}")
    private int minimum;

    @Value("${maximum}")
    private int maximum;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int port;

    //Methods
}
```

It may be a name conflict according to `Configuration`.

Comment: I have tried it but all variable type is **String** if we read properties with **@Value**,
It is difficult to convert each and every property from **String** to required type